# Redirect to modified URL using .htaccess with parameter

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

I am not too familiar with htaccess. My current URL is: `https://example.com/wp-admin/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F?latepoint_booking_intent_key=e9176adf75c89661f6ca` but I would like this to be redirected to `https://example.com/?latepoint_booking_intent_key=e9176adf75c89661f6ca` . How can I do this with .htaccess?

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^wp-admin/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F/?$ ?latepoint_booking_intent_key=$1  [R=301,L,NC]
```

However, the new URL is:

`https://example.com/wp-admin/https://example.com/?latepoint_booking_intent_key=e9176adf75c89661f6cc`  and this is not correct

Is there an .htaccess expert that can help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Use `RewriteCond` directive to match the query string in the URL :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(latepoint_booking_intent_key=.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?%1 [R=301,L]
```

[Test](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=a5a70328-00a7-4e83-b690-9e38c338430a)

Comment: I get 404 error when I test this on my website. Not entirely sure why as this should work as shown in the tester. Do you have any ideas? Rewrite is already enabled and AllowOverride All is in my apache config.

Comment: @Ské Did it work on incognito?